# Getting Mechanize::UnauthorizedError: 401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized when accessing API with Basic Auth

Tags: mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to access an API using Basic Auth. It works with HTTParty, but not with 2.7.6 Mechanize.

This is what I tried:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.log = Logger.new(STDERR)
agent.add_auth("https://website.net/listingapi", "user", "pass")
page = agent.get("https://website.net/listingapi")
```

And this is what I get:

```
 INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /listingapi
DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding => gzip,deflate,identity
DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent => Mechanize/2.7.6 Ruby/2.5.3p105 (http://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/)
DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
DEBUG -- : request-header: host => website.net
 INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPUnauthorized 1.1 401 Unauthorized
DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => application/json; charset=utf-8
DEBUG -- : response-header: www-authenticate => Bearer, Basic realm=ListingApi
DEBUG -- : response-header: date => Wed, 13 Mar 2019 14:14:51 GMT
DEBUG -- : response-header: content-length => 61
DEBUG -- : response-header: x-xss-protection => 1; mode=block
DEBUG -- : response-header: strict-transport-security => max-age=31536000
DEBUG -- : response-header: x-content-type-options => nosniff
DEBUG -- : Read 61 bytes (61 total)
Mechanize::UnauthorizedError: 401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized for https://website.net/listingapi/ -- no credentials found, provide some with #add_auth -- available realms: 
from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@mygems/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:749:in `response_authenticate'
```

What am I doing wrong, or what is wrong with the API response?

PS. I found this, which I think might be related: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/pull/442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When basic auth is used, username and password are joined together and then encoded using base64. The encoded resulted string is sent to the server in `Authorization` header using [Basic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme)

Now a workaround you can do in case you have issues using `add_auth` is to pass the Authorization header yourself:

```
username = 'Radu'
password = 'mypassword'
agent = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.pre_connect_hooks << lambda { |agent, request| request["Authorization"] = "Basic #{Base64.strict_encode64(username + ':' + password)}" }
end
page = agent.get("https://website.net/listingapi")
```

**Edit 1**

Now that I read the logs again I can see that `www-authenticate` header says `Bearer, Basic realm=ListingApi`. Instead it should say `Basic realm=ListingApi`.

The problem is [response_authenticate](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/b959fb10d2e5943e69c268993481a1b73c80717e/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb#L745) can't find any challange most likely because the API you're requesting does not respect this part of [RFC7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) regarding the challenge.

The missing challenge raises 401 after [this line](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/b959fb10d2e5943e69c268993481a1b73c80717e/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb#L747)

```
[1] pry(main)> authenticate_parser  = Mechanize::HTTP::WWWAuthenticateParser.new
=> #<Mechanize::HTTP::WWWAuthenticateParser:0x00007fe2a5c74ec8 @scanner=nil>

[2] pry(main)> authenticate_parser.parse "Basic realm=ListingApi"
=> [#<struct Mechanize::HTTP::AuthChallenge scheme=nil, params=nil, raw=nil>]

[3] pry(main)> authenticate_parser.parse "Bearer, Basic realm=ListingApi"
=> []
```

**Edit 2**

The reason why HTTParty works is that they add the [Authorization header upfront](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/290aa62c335c3d5672a76a557ff7e1f1daeeed16/lib/httparty/request.rb#L237) directly on Net::HTTP::Get. Mechanize utilizes whole challenge-response authorization and they will only add it if the challenge scheme is `Basic`.

Comment: So what should be different concretely in the API response?

Comment: API should send back `www-authenticate: Basic realm=ListingApi`. The reason why HTTParty works is that [they add the Authorization header](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/290aa62c335c3d5672a76a557ff7e1f1daeeed16/lib/httparty/request.rb#L237) upfront. Mechanize utilizes the RFC7235 and they inspect the response and do the whole challenge-response authorization.

Comment: Same "issue" was found in the mechanize perl module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404920/setting-basic-authentication-credentials-in-wwwmechanize